# Absolute html element position inside the browser relative to display

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to get know exact position and visible size of the html element inside
the browser window relative to the entire display.

I'm not interresting in the absolute position inside the HTML document.

My task is to make automated screenshot of the HTML element
as it is represented on the display.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your tags only include HTML, which isn't a scripting language. Please add tags to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate (assuming JavaScript): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element